# Can you assign different buttons for different views using a split view controller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, uisplitviewcontroller

I am creating a split view ipad app. I have four buttons in the master view which segue to four different views. However, when I am in certain views I don't need all of those buttons to display in the toolbar. So basically, is it possible to change the buttons for different views in a split view controller? any advice, tutorials, or source code would be sweet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to what Lu Yuan said. You could put a pointer to the instance of the master view in your app delegate so that when one of your subviews load, it can get the master view instance. Then you can hide which ever master view buttons you want.